# How to access a Docker container in the local network?

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, docker-network

I have pulled an MYSQL image from Docker Hub and ran it by setting necessary credentials, such as username, password etc. Then I have inspected the container by:

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_ID
```

where I got the IP address for the MySQL databese. Since the Docker deamon connect through bridge network, my IP addess was: 172.17.0.2. By specifying this IP I can connnect to the Database from the host computer(Fedora). But, how do I connectd to the MySQL database from another machine in the same LAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the container port to a host machine port. Adding `-p` to the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
```

I.e.:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 .......
```

So MySQL is available from the Fedora's LAN interface.

Comment: after I have followed your instruction I this from docker inspect: "...Ports" : "3306tct": [{"HostIp": "192.168.20.109}, "HostPort": "3306"}]... and then I have tried from my other pc: mysql -u root -h 192.168.20.109:3306 -p, but I got Unknown MySQL Server host error.

Comment: The port must be specified as this: `mysql -u root -h 192.168.20.109 -P 3306 -p`. Or just not specify any because it is default.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now by following the instruction above.